# JQuery change input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on the webpage which contains a input field that needs to be changed programmatically using stored string into the php variable.

This is my JQuery code and it is doing what i need.

```
$(function(){
$('.start').click(function(e) {
    var currentPage = "<?php echo $name;?>";
   $('input').val(currentPage);
   $('.textfield').prop("disabled", true );
   $('.textfield').css('cursor','not-allowed');
});
});
```

When I click start button name is inserted into the input element, but when i click submit button, error message popup that "Field is required".
My question is, why changed input value doesn't work. If I add or remove letter then submit button is working and there is no field message popup.

Thanks

Comment: can you past your full code along with html

Comment: share the method which is giving the alert

Comment: can you try `$('input').val(currentPage).change();`

Comment: Ya, changing value programatically doesn't fire any event. Now it's hard to figure if it is your issue with so little info and relevant code in question itself. How FORM is validated?

Comment: $('input').val(currentPage).change(); - does not work, already tried that.
It is Ispring Quiz Maker app and html is generated through the JS and Json.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled fields won't get submitted by forms. Hence, it says "Field is required". But there is another property which can be helpful in this kind of situation. Use readonly property. Replace the following line in your code instead of disabled property.

```
$('.textfield').prop("readonly", true );
```

Let us know if this solved the issue.

Comment: Changed, but nothing, This is Quiz made with Ispring Quiz Maker and I think that problem is in the main player.js. I don't get it how submit works if i write something, but if value is changed using JQuery it doesn't.

Comment: You sure that your validation works fine? We can submit forms when values are added using JQuery. I can't guess what exactly the problem is. Share the part of your html and js (validation part) that you suspect.